# Get status of handling request by Spring's ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest() method

Tags: java, spring

I have the code like:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws IOException {
    resourceHttpRequestHandler = new ResourceHttpRequestHandler();
    resourceHttpRequestHandler.setServletContext(servletContext);
    resourceHttpRequestHandler.setLocations(... my locations here... );
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/mypath/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getResource(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    resourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(request, response);
    /* here */
}
```

Is it possible to know if the resolving of resource request was successful or not (after the call of method `handleRequest()` )?

Comment: Why are you using a controller to wrap a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`? Why aren't you simply using the namespace..

Comment: It's because there are a lot of other logic which I didn't write here just because it's not related to the current problem :)

Comment: Still I find it dubious to wrap a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` in a controller. You could check the status code for the response but that is about it what you can do, the request is already handled by the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` itself so there isn't anything you can do about it.